# How can shared_ptr convert to a private base class?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, c++11, type-conversion

In the following inheritance structure, `IFace` is a private base class of `Face`:

```
class IFace{};

class Face : /*private*/ IFace{};
```

While a conversion from raw `Face*` to `IFace*` pointers of course fails, `shared_ptr<Face>` can still be converted to a `shared_ptr<IFace>`,

```
shared_ptr<Face> s_face = make_shared<Face>();
shared_ptr<IFace> s_iface = s_face; //works

Face* p_face = new Face();
IFace* p_iface = p_face; //compiler complains (righteously) 
                         //about the base class being inaccessible
```

What magic tricks is `shared_ptr` playing here?

Is this behaviour covered by the standard, or is it specific to my implementation (MSVC12)?

Does the newly created `s_iface` share its reference count with `s_face`?

Comment: This succeeds on gcc 4.8.1 when using public inheritance, but [fails](http://ideone.com/JrZXAA) when using private inheritance: *"error: conversion from ‘std::shared_ptr<Face>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::shared_ptr<IFace>’ requested"*

Comment: [Fails](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d95a2b5429f863fc) with clang/libc++ as well, so I'm going to go with a MSVC bug.

Comment: I don't think the `shared_ptr` behavior here is standard, but in general, you can convert to pointer or reference to inaccessible base via a C style cast. It's a special case of that cast. I.e. it's not a `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard requires the converting constructor be SFINAE'd out (the standardese is "shall not participate in overload resolution") if the pointers are not implicitly convertible. This looks like a bug in MSVC's implementation of `std::is_convertible`:

```
#include <type_traits>
class IFace {};

class Face : /*private*/ IFace{};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<Face *, IFace *>::value, "Face * is not convertible to IFace *");
    static_assert(!std::is_convertible<Face *, IFace *>::value, "Face * is convertible to IFace *");
}
```

Gives me `error C2338: Face * is convertible to IFace *` using MSVC12.

Both clang and g++ correctly fail at the first `static_assert` and report `Face * is not convertible to IFace *`.

Looking at MSVC's `<type_traits>` header, `is_convertible` is implemented with a compiler built-in, so it boils down to a compiler bug.